# Is it possible to hot reload server side code with webpack?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I know hot reloading works for client side code such as react, but is it possible to do the same for server side code?

For example, I have a rest api in express. If I change an endpoint, could I get the server to reload without re-bundling with webpack?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can even setup different webpack configs for server vs. client, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Razzle does hot reload on both client and server without restarting.
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle